# Persist GradientTape after Construction

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

Is it possible to set persistence of a `GradientTape` after its construction?

The use case is when I have code that I don't control pass a non-persistent tape to me, with which I must take two gradients with dependencies between them.

```py
# I don't control this
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y = f(x)
    z = g(y)

# I control this
dzdx = tape.gradient(z, x)
result = tape.gradient(z, y, output_gradients=dzdx)  # not persistent
```

I've pondered the possibility of simply setting `tape._persistent` before calling `gradient`, but the persistence gets [passed all the way](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py#L856) to C++ code at construction, which probably won't like being inconsistent with the Python code

```py
def push_new_tape(persistent=False, watch_accessed_variables=True):
  """Pushes a new tape onto the tape stack."""
  tape = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_TapeSetNew(persistent, watch_accessed_variables)
  return Tape(tape)
```

Which ultimately [ends up at](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/eager/tape.h#L125)

```cpp
template <typename Gradient, typename BackwardFunction, typename TapeTensor>
class GradientTape {
 public:
  // If `persistent` is true, GradientTape will not eagerly delete backward
  // functions (and hence the tensors they keep alive). Instead, everything
  // is deleted in ~GradientTape. Persistent GradientTapes are useful when
  // users want to compute multiple gradients over the same tape.
  explicit GradientTape(bool persistent) : persistent_(persistent) {}
  ~GradientTape() {
    for (const auto& pair : op_tape_) {
      pair.second.backward_function_deleter(pair.second.backward_function);
    }
  }

  // ...

  bool IsPersistent() const { return persistent_; }
```

Where `IsPersistent` is the only public interface to `persistent_`. I can't tell how exactly `persistent_` is used, and that sounds like a memory leak in waiting.

Comment: A quick test shows that setting `persistent_` to True after construction will not make the tape actually persistent anyway.